# Find a file with particular text on a remote machine using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to find a file on a remote server which contains specific text in it. If there are multiple files it should list all the files containing this text.

Below is the statement I had been able to make but unfortunately I get an error message while executing. Please advise.

Command:

```
sshpass -p abc123 ssh root@192.168.1.102 find /root/Downloads/test/app/beta/System* -type f -mmin -60 | xargs grep -E "put"
```

Error Message:

```
grep: /root/Downloads/test/app/beta/SystemOut_qqq: No such file or directory
grep: /root/Downloads/test/app/beta/SystemOut_qwp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard is being expanded locally. You need to quote it in order to pass it through to the remote host.

Also, in order for `grep` to be able to examine those files, it too needs to run on the remote host, so we quote the entire command line.

As per your stated requirements, I added an `-l` option to list files containing a match, instead of print each match. Because your example expression is a static string, I changed from `grep -E` to `grep -F`. If you want to search for regular expressions, you might want to undo that change.

```
sshpass -p abc123 ssh root@192.168.1.102 'find /root/Downloads/test/app/beta/System* -type f -mmin -60 | xargs grep -F -l "put"'
```

Comment: Sorry but I got the same error as before.

grep: /root/Downloads/test/app/beta/SystemOut_qqq: No such file or directory
grep: /root/Downloads/test/app/beta/SystemOut_qwp: No such file or directory

Comment: The command is finding the newly modified two files but only the "SystemOut_qqq" has the "put" text in it. However the output i get is "No such file or directory" along with the file names as above.

Comment: Sorry, careless edit resulted in wrong quoting in spite of my own instructions. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
sshpass -p abc123 ssh root@192.168.1.102 find /root/Downloads/test/app/beta/System -type f -mmin -60 -exec grep -E "put" {} \;
```

Comment: Got and error message as find: missing argument to `-exec'